# Getting Random Nulls on .querySelector() in for Loop

Tags: javascript, html, filter

```
<div id="agg-filter-buttons">

<button class="btn filter-btn"  onclick="filterSelection(event)"><span data- 
 value="freespins">Free Spins <div class="num-brands"></div> </span></button>

    <button class="btn filter-btn"  onclick="filterSelection(event)"> <span data-value="bigbonus">Big Bonus <div class="num-brands"></div>  </span></button>  </div>
    enter code here

</div>
```

> 

```
    <div class="brand-row the-table-row all row-1 filterDiv bigbonus newPlay show">
      Row 1
     </div>
   
       <div class="brand-row the-table-row all row-2 filterDiv freespins  newPlay show">
        Row 2
       </div>


 filterSelection();
  function filterSelection(e) {
    var x, i, c;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    var allBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn")
    for(i = 0; i<allBtns.length; i++){
      let rowsAffected = allBtns[i].querySelector('.num-brands');
      rowsAffected.innerText = '';
    }
      c = "all";
      if(e && e.target.dataset){
        c = e.target.dataset.value ? e.target.dataset.value : "all";
      }
    const numBrands = [];
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove('show');
      void x[i].offsetWidth;
          if (x[i].classList.contains(c)) {
            x[i].classList.add('show');
            numBrands.push(i);
          }
    }
    if(e && e.target){
      e.srcElement.children[0].innerText =  ` (${numBrands.length})`;
    }
  }
  // Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("agg-filter-buttons");
  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn");

  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function($this) {
      var current = document.querySelectorAll(".active-btn");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active-btn", "");
      this.className += " active-btn";
    });
  }

  var filter = document.getElementById('agg-filter-buttons');
  filter.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('section--btable')[0].classList.add('flash');
  });
```

```js
filterSelection();

function filterSelection(e) {
  var x, i, c;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  var allBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn")
  for (i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++) {
    let rowsAffected = allBtns[i].querySelector('.num-brands');
    rowsAffected.innerText = '';
  }
  c = "all";
  if (e && e.target.dataset) {
    c = e.target.dataset.value ? e.target.dataset.value : "all";
  }
  const numBrands = [];
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.remove('show');
    void x[i].offsetWidth;
    if (x[i].classList.contains(c)) {
      x[i].classList.add('show');
      numBrands.push(i);
    }
  }
  if (e && e.target) {
    e.srcElement.children[0].innerText = ` (${numBrands.length})`;
  }
}
// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("agg-filter-buttons");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("filter-btn");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function($this) {
    var current = document.querySelectorAll(".active-btn");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active-btn", "");
    this.className += " active-btn";
  });
}

var filter = document.getElementById('agg-filter-buttons');
filter.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('section--btable')[0].classList.add('flash');
});
```

```html
<div id="agg-filter-buttons">

  <button class="btn filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection(event)"><span data- 
     value="freespins">Free Spins <div class="num-brands"></div> </span></button>

  <button class="btn filter-btn" onclick="filterSelection(event)"> <span data-value="bigbonus">Big Bonus <div class="num-brands"></div>  </span></button> </div>
enter code here

</div>

>
<div class="brand-row the-table-row all row-1 filterDiv bigbonus newPlay show">
  Row 1
</div>

<div class="brand-row the-table-row all row-2 filterDiv freespins  newPlay show">
  Row 2
</div>
```

So I have a table with rows. These are filtered with the filter buttons. When you click a filter button it shows only the rows with the same name in its class. This works and populates the button with how many rows are affected.
However this breaks occasionally and I have no idea why.
the Variable rowsAffected works until it becomes null for some unknown reason.

My guess is that the dom eventually doesnt load fast enough for the querySelector to be able to read it. But im not sure.. Any advice very welcome!

I have also added a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8z56sxby/

Comment: Why are you mixing getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll? Just do it with querySelectorAll

Comment: I made a snippet of the code presented including the syntax errors you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only care about the first .active-btn (because there is at most one), you can just use querySelector.

Make sure there is a `current` before you do anything with its classes.

Use element.classList.add and element.classList.remove to add or remove classes.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var current = document.querySelector(".active-btn");
      if (current) current.classList.remove("active-btn");
      this.classList.add("active-btn");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou
The answer to this question was that clicks on my button were sometimes clicking child elements which were not setup to handle the click.
A silly mistake - that someone may find useful in the future.